# AngularFire2: Create document and set an array of maps

Tags: arrays, typescript, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2, angularfire

**Requested behaviour:** 
I would like to create an AngularService which adds a document to Firestore with two fields. The first field is a map which is filled with user data. The second field is an array of maps. It should receive the map from the first field as the first item.

**Current State** 
The function creates and fills the document successfully if I only add the map (first field) and comment out the array of maps(second field).

**issue** 
If I add code for setting the array, the function does not work anymore. I receive the following error even both fields are called with the same data:

> FirebaseError: Function DocumentReference.set() called with invalid
>   data. Unsupported field value: undefined (found in field
>   groupExecutiveBoard)

How can I fix that? How can I create the array of maps and push the first map to it?

**My Model:**

```js
export interface Group {

    groupLeader?: {
        groupLeaderID?: string;
        groupLeaderName?: string;
        groupLeaderImage?: string;
    };
    
    //array
    groupExecutiveBoard?: {
        boardMemberID?: string;
        boardMemberName?: string;
        boardMemberImage?: string;
    }[];
    
}
```

**My Service**

```js
constructor(private angularFirestore: AngularFirestore) { }

addGroup(author: User) {
  const groupsCollection = this.angularFirestore.collection<GroupID>('groups');

  groupsCollection.add({

    // sets groupleader if "GroupExecutiveBoard" is commented out
    groupLeader: {
      groupLeaderID: author.uid,
      groupLeaderName: author.displayName,
      groupLeaderImage: author.profilePhoto
    },

    //should set user data as first array item. Does not work
    groupExecutiveBoard: {
      boardMemberId: author.uid,
      boardMemberName: author.displayName,
      boardMemberImage: author.profilePhoto
    }[0],

  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out:

```
groupLeader: {
      groupLeaderID: author.uid,
      groupLeaderName: author.displayName,
      groupLeaderImage: author.profilePhoto
    },
groupExecutiveBoard: [{
      boardMemberId: author.uid,
      boardMemberName: author.displayName,
      boardMemberImage: author.profilePhoto
}],
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that does not work. I get multiple ts lints then - including `The expected type comes from property 'groupExecutiveBoard' which is declared here on type 'GroupID'`. As far as I know, this means. that I can not assign you approach to an object[] array type

Comment: I updated my answer. Try to change the curley braces with the square brackets

Comment: I am so sorry. I think your first solution was correct. I made a typo in my post description here (in my code the last letter of boardMemberID is a capital "D", here it is a "d") and then copy pasted your solution to my code. Can you bring up your first solution again? Then I could mark it as solved :) Thanks for your help already!

Comment: But did you tried the update? Because that creates a map in an array. Wasn't that what you tried to do or is it fine for you with strings?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand you correctly. This is my code now: `groupExecutiveBoard: [{
        boardMemberID: author.uid,
        boardMemberName: author.displayName,
        boardMemberImage: author.profilePhoto
      }],` And it creates an array and every item of the array is a map. So it creates exactly my expected behaviour.

Comment: Ok, know I got what you mean :) I changed to my first solution again.